# Not able to get selected radio button value in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am working on AngularJs(1.x) I have dynamically created radio buttons. There is a "submit" button below the radio buttons which sends the selected value to the backend.

But problem is, I always get "undefined" as selected radio button value in my controller. Could you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Below is my HTML code:

```
 <table>
           <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
              <td><input type="radio" name="userinputs" ng-model="selectedValues[detail.path]" /></td>
              <td class="text">{{detail.created_time}}</td>
              <td class="text">{{detail.path}}</td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    <button type="button" ng-click="submitAction()>
```

Below is the code in my controller:

```
$scope.selectedValues = [];
$scope.submitAction = function(){
   console.log("selected values:",$scope.selectedValues); //empty array
}
```

Can someone tell that what is right way to fetch value of dynamically created radio button?

**EDIT**: Since a person in comment section asked me how "details" array look like.."details" array is an array of object. Here is the sample:

```
[
  {
    "created_time": "2018-06-14 09:15:59.923639",
    "path": "hdfs://rhel-sp1-hadoop-mgr-1.node.dc1.pnda.local:8…da/flink/savepoints/savepoint-748ad1-284636263a29",
    "$$hashKey": "object:124"
  },
  {
    "created_time": "2018-06-14 09:17:33.913376",
    "path": "hdfs://rhel-sp1-hadoop-mgr-1.node.dc1.pnda.local:8…da/flink/savepoints/savepoint-748ad1-303080089004",
    "$$hashKey": "object:125"
  },
  {
    "created_time": "2018-06-14 09:22:17.562679",
    "path": "hdfs://rhel-sp1-hadoop-mgr-1.node.dc1.pnda.local:8…da/flink/savepoints/savepoint-748ad1-ea56f40fc986",
    "$$hashKey": "object:126"
  }
]
```

Comment: What does the `details` array look like?

Comment: It is an array of object. It looks like this:
[
  {
    "created_time": "2018-06-14 09:15:59.923639",
    "path": "hdfs://rhel-sp1-hadoop-mgr-1.node.dc1.pnda.local:8…da/flink/savepoints/savepoint-748ad1-284636263a29",
    "$$hashKey": "object:124"
  },
  {
    "created_time": "2018-06-14 09:17:33.913376",
    "path": "hdfs://rhel-sp1-hadoop-mgr-1.node.dc1.pnda.local:8…da/flink/savepoints/savepoint-748ad1-303080089004",
    "$$hashKey": "object:125"
  }
]

Comment: @Protozoid Please see in my questions. I edited that question with detail array value

Answer (score 1):

pass the ng-model value as a parameter in the ng-click function as below on submit

```
<table>
               <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
                  <td><input type="radio" ng-value="detail" name="userinputs" ng-model="data.selectedValues" /></td>
                  <td class="text">{{detail.created_time}}</td>
                  <td class="text">{{detail.path}}</td>
                </tr>
          </table>
        <button type="button" ng-click="submitAction(data.selectedValues)">
```

Comment: Then also it comes empty

Comment: I have edited the answer. make use of ng-value and instead of assign name to ng-model make it data.selectedValues

Answer (score 0):

you can not use the ng-model in that way, in the ng-model you can only assign the values ​​that correspond to the html element that you assign it to.
Example:
if you use it in an  the ng-model will only assign true or false to the variable because this radiobutton or checkbuttons only handle boolean values

In your case you have several ways to solve the problem depending on what you want to do:

**Soluction 1:**if you want add several selected values

```
 <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
                       <td>
                         <input type="checkbox" name="userinputs" ng-click="addSelectedValue(detail)" ng-model="someModel" /></td>
                       <td class="text">{{detail.created_time}}</td>
                       <td class="text">{{detail.path}}</td>
                     </tr>
               </table>
             <button type="button" ng-click="submitAction()">Sugmit</button>
```

// JAVASCRIP CODE

```
 $scope.selectedValues = [];

//add or remove selected value
$scope.addSelectedValue = function(value){
    let i = $scope.selectedValues.indexOf(value);
    // if values exist in array, remove  from selected values
    if(i>=0){
         $scope.selectedValues.splice(i,1);
    }
    //else add to selected values
    else{
        $scope.selectedValues.push(value);
    }
}
//submit values
$scope.submitAction = function(){
    $scope.selectedValues;
}
```

**Solution 2:** if you only want selected one value it is easier

```
 <controller ng-controller="main">
                <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
                       <td>
                         <input type="radio" name="userinputs" ng-click="selectedValue = detail" ng-model="someModel" /></td>
                       <td class="text">{{detail.created_time}}</td>
                       <td class="text">{{detail.path}}</td>
                     </tr>
               </table>
             <button type="button" ng-click="submitAction()">Sugmit</button>
            </controller>
```

// JAVASCRIPT

```
$scope.selectedValue = {};
//submit values
$scope.submitAction = function(){
    $scope.selectedValue;
}
```

in both solutions
i used ng-click event to capture the value (you can use ng-change), the point is that you need some event to assign a value to a variable.

but if you want use ng-model, you can do this.

**Solution 3**

```
<controller ng-controller="main">
                <table>
                    <tr ng-repeat="detail in details">
                       <td>
                         <input type="radio" name="userinputs"  ng-model="detail.isSelected" /></td>
                       <td class="text">{{detail.created_time}}</td>
                       <td class="text">{{detail.path}}</td>
                     </tr>
               </table>
             <button type="button" ng-click="submitAction()">Sugmit</button>
            </controller>
```

// JAVASCRIPT

```
//submit values
$scope.submitAction = function(){
   //select all the values that are marked as selected
    let selectedValues = $scope.details.filter((values)=>values.isSeleted==true);
}
```